# Why i am not getting Volley StringRequest response string from **onResponse(String response)** method

Tags: android, android-volley

i am sending a post request using volley stringrequest the code is as give below :

```
 StringRequest request  = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, StaticConstant.LOGIN_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Where","inside Response"+response.toString());
                loginCallback.onLoginSuccess(true,response.toString());
            }
        },

    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e("Where","inside error Response"+error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("inputtype","json");
        params.put("inputstring", "{\"AuthenticateVendorRQ\":{\"Credentials\":{\"APIKey\":\"\",\"CompanyCode\":\"\",\"VendorCode\":\"1\"}}}");
        params.put("responsetype", "xml");
        return params;
    }
```

the callback (**loginCallback.onLoginSuccess(true,response.toString())**) is not getting the String response value in the class where i am using it.
the response from .net based webservice is :

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"AuthenticateVendorRS":{"Status":"FAIL","ErrorCode":"","ErrorMessage":""}}
</string>
```

my question is when it is in onResponse(String response) then why response value is not there? could anybody help me?

Comment: If not string response, what are you getting?

Comment: as you can see in onResponse() the log even is not printed there but the callback is called  Log.e("Where","inside Response"+response.toString()); so i m not sure about the result but if it is in onResponse() there must be some value

Comment: If the response is empty, I think that maybe you don't send the right parameters.

Comment: if it is empty then it should print the Log at least, but its even not printing that

Comment: can you post server side code

Comment: Its a SOAP base web service, and i have checked the code it works fine on GET and POST both the request, i have also checked it on POSTMAN

Comment: Run in Debug mode you get where is your code get issue.

Comment: thanks all i got the solution . . . .

Comment: Please share the solution with all @AbhishekKumar